# Rails devise does not remove the cookie on log out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise

When the user logged out because of marking the current_user as closed.

The user move to login page.

but if I try to enter with another active user.
I cant logged in until I clear the cookies.

Seems that the "old" session keeped and not deleted.

How can I force remove the cookie on loggedout

This is my validate code

```
def active_for_authentication?
super && !self.site.try(:is_closed)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using

```
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

?

That's devise built in mechanism to log out the user. It handles cookie removing and session destroying itself.

**Edit:**

The appreciated way to destroy the user session is
destroy_user_session_path(@user). But I guess you are already doing this, aren't you? Do you know what's the name of the cookie which makes the problems?

Comment: the error is while the user mark as "closed" status, not by clicking the logout link.

Comment: This doesn't work when I am making an API request.